# How do I get sar to show for the previous day?

Tags: linux, command-line, load, statistics

on our servers, typing `sar` show's the system load statistics for today starting at midnight, is it possible to show yesterdays statistics?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Usually, [sysstat](http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/documentation.html), which provides a `sar` command, keeps logs in `/var/log/sysstat/` or `/var/log/sa/` with filenames such as `/var/log/sysstat/sadd` where `dd` is a numeric value for the day of the month (starting at 01).  By default, the file from the current day is used; however, you can change the file that is used with the `-f` command line switch.  Thus for the 3rd of the month you would do something like:

```
sar -f /var/log/sysstat/sa03
```

If you want to restrict the time range, you can use the `-s` and `-e` parameters.  If you want to routinely get yesterday's file and can never remember the date and have GNU date you could try

```
sar -f /var/log/sysstat/sa$(date +%d -d yesterday)
```

I highly recommend reading the [manual page for sar](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sar).

Comment: on our cPanel/CentOS systems it appears to be in `/var/log/sa`

Comment: yup, centos it's: sar -b -f /var/log/sa/sa20 for the 20th of the month.

Comment: /var/log/sa for Redhat as well

Comment: /var/log/sa in SUSE too

Answer (score 8):

Try the command as follows to get historic memory utilization details.

```
sar -r -f /var/log/sa/sa01
```

The files in `/var/log/sa` record everything in the world.

Answer (score 7):

There is a "magic" parameter for that: `-N`, e.g. the following would display the yesterday's stats:

```
sar -1
```

Collect weekly data from many servers, put it to NFS:

```
parallel --tag --nonall -k -j 3 -S server1,server2,server3 \
  'of="/nfs-path/sar-$(hostname).out"; rm -f "${of}"; for N in {7..0}; do sar -A -$N 2> /dev/null >> "${of}"; done'
```

Those files can be loaded into [kSar](https://github.com/vlsi/ksar)

Comment: this is so much better than the accepted answer, it's built into sar command, exactly what I hoped it could do!